# Typescript: Using conditional types and optional variables to map one string to another

Tags: typescript

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsMCAq4IB5kD4oF4rJQQAewEAdgCYDOU1wATgJbkDmUA-FAESUCGwPtygAuKOTgAbSQG4AUHIBmccgGNgTAPbkoAWz5hMRUhRp1GLdgB8oKyhEUsIlADRQAasbJVa8RCjRMLCwACjkoKBYkYAAxJkkIMWQ5AEoxTwBvcKgGCGA4Bh0QqIQ4hM4efkFhMQlpFKg%20Wnd5AF8FZTUNbT0DGDBu8j5JdGzCEm8zemY2KBs7BydKPFsqRfJnF2zPCdNfBGjUSCCVv0PA7DlQktj4iA4ktI8oLIjc-MKoYvJosuguXgCISicRSSQNJoeNoKVTaei9MAARhW%20jAIW4jgSACZuCl5E1qBAGMBkAw4BgjhAAKIARzgw3QgOqblAkE0igRiOCITxclh5HhqKxKIM6OIwkh00sc1W9kcG0ovIJRJJZIpaFp9JGTOBNjqkhZaHZCKx3N5-MFBgAzCK0Qt5c4ldRCcTSeTMBq6Qz9Ya2RzUVazfILcAEQAWW08mRQAD0MaIDAYmgYcmVrrVHsgmu9YN9EGNqLDQdj8aJSZTfLhodR-UGw2R%20BrAy0Q0k6MxEBxTpdqvdlOz2qqQjzBb6ze09aDlYF1bHdckwsbc5bwzFEtoUtm8zWDsV%20OdKrd6qzXsHQOEetzUFZ%20f9y4nC%20LcYT5enlrAtZXkhtS4-49bIT2ks3aHhm-anugPrXkad5-vOgahOaVYIp%20D4Rr%20qEASB6Z9p6WqQVeN6jnBX5Foh8hyDGABUVFQLRAAieREroTi0EwHI3rQAAGAAaXGNFQUBcQAmvxfC5EQp4AHQRFRMZyDeBB4QyPFuMJOD4CEQQ8ngODjCYPhQDxFSMOSIKKMMhINLshmjBEySIbpBBeHsUDCSZarmZZEDZFwpk%20REYgWZIhIUdRtG0QAggexK0Hw0GQEQABuwz0mQtDAJo16eXJcj2KokjidAnTqC2jQxb2GAAPr6ZMGVqohYhJZoTCUDIQA)

I am trying to create a generic function that can essentially map one string to another at compile time.  If any string is inputted, then `" data"` should be returned, if undefined, then `null` should be returned.  The problem is based on making `input file optional.

I have it almost working w/with different functions, but I have test cases that fail for both that I have marked with `error` below.  I also have a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsMCAq4IB5kD4oF4rJQQAewEAdgCYDOU1wATgJbkDmUA-FAESUCGwPtygAuKOTgAbSQG4AUHIBmccgGNgTAPbkoAWz5hMRUhRp1GLdgB8oKyhEUsIlADRQAasbJVa8RCjRMLCwACjkoKBYkYAAxJkkIMWQ5AEoxTwBvcKgGCGA4Bh0QqIQ4hM4efkFhMQlpFKg%20Wnd5AF8FZTUNbT0DGDBu8j5JdGzCEm8zemY2KBs7BydKPFsqRfJnF2zPCdNfBGjUSCCVv0PA7DlQktj4iA4ktI8oLIjc-MKoYvJosuguXgCISicRSSQNJoeNoKVTaei9MAARhW%20jAIW4jgSACZuCl5E1qBAGMBkAw4BgjhAAKIARzgw3QgOqblAkE0igRiOCITxclh5HhqKxKIM6OIwkh00sc1W9kcG0ovIJRJJZIpaFp9JGTOBNjqkhZaHZCKx3N5-MFBgAzCK0Qt5c4ldRCcTSeTMBq6Qz9Ya2RzUVazfILcAEQAWW08mRQAD0MaIDAYmgYcmVrrVHsgmu9YN9EGNqLDQdj8aJSZTfLhodR-UGw2R%20BrAy0Q0k6MxEBxTpdqvdlOz2qqQjzBb6ze09aDlYF1bHdckwsbc5bwzFEtoUtm8zWDsV%20OdKrd6qzXsHQOEetzUFZ%20f9y4nC%20LcYT5enlrAtZXkhtS4-49bIT2ks3aHhm-anugPrXkad5-vOgahOaVYIp%20D4Rr%20qEASB6Z9p6WqQVeN6jnBX5Foh8hyDGABUVFQLRAAieREroTi0EwHI3rQAAGAAaXGNFQUBcQAmvxfC5EQp4AHQRFRMZyDeBB4QyPFuMJOD4CEQQ8ngODjCYPhQDxFSMOSIKKMMhINLshmjBEySIbpBBeHsUDCSZarmZZEDZFwpk%20REYgWZIhIUdRtG0QAggexK0Hw0GQEQABuwz0mQtDAJo16eXJcj2KokjidAnTqC2jQxb2GAAPr6ZMGVqohYhJZoTCUDIQA) setup.

```
type OutputType<T> = T extends string ? "data" : null;

function map<T extends string | undefined, V extends OutputType<T>>(
  inputFile: T
): V {
  return (inputFile ? "data" : null) as V;
}

function mapOptional<
  T extends string | undefined = undefined,
  V extends OutputType<T> = OutputType<T>
>(inputFile?: T): V {
  return (inputFile ? "data" : null) as V;
}

const map1 = map("file2");
assertTrue<TypeEqual<"data", typeof map1>>();
const map2 = map("x" as string | undefined);
assertTrue<TypeEqual<"data" | null, typeof map2>>();
const map3 = map(undefined);
assertTrue<TypeEqual<null, typeof map3>>();
const map4 = map(); // error
assertTrue<TypeEqual<null, typeof map4>>(); // error

const mapOptional1 = mapOptional("file2");
assertTrue<TypeEqual<"data", typeof mapOptional1>>();
const mapOptional2 = mapOptional("x" as string | undefined);
assertTrue<TypeEqual<"data" | null, typeof mapOptional2>>(); // error
const mapOptional3 = mapOptional(undefined);
assertTrue<TypeEqual<null, typeof mapOptional3>>();
const mapOptional4 = mapOptional();
assertTrue<TypeEqual<null, typeof mapOptional4>>();
```

Comment: Please mark where you have expected errors

Comment: I already marked them with `error`

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky one, because the optionality of the parameter is not explicitly part of its generic type.

I managed to work around that by just using multiple function declarations:

```
function mapOptional(): null;
function mapOptional(inputFile: undefined): null;
function mapOptional<T extends string>(inputFile: T): 'data';
function mapOptional<T extends string | undefined>(inputFile: T): 'data' | null;
function mapOptional<
  T extends string | undefined
>(inputFile?: T): 'data' | null {
  return (inputFile ? "data" : null) as any;
}
```